# Using values from a struct in the compare function in qsort() - C99 - Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, c99, qsort

i am fairly new to c and struggling to properly use the C stdlib qsort() function.

This is relevant to education and as such i am only allowed to use C99 and standard libraries if this is important.

I have a list of items taken from a HashTable and put into a HashItem **array but then when sorting this i am struggling with the compare function, i cannot get the correct value out of the struct. I have looked around and seen a few solutions but they all seem to lead to a

```
[Error] dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Here is the struct :

```
typedef struct {
char *word;
int occurences;
} HashItem;
```

And i am interested in comparing and sorting by the occurences value.

Here is the bit of code which calls the qsort:

```
int n = array->number_of_values;
HashItem **standard_array = array_getarray(array); 
qsort(standard_array, n, sizeof(HashItem*), compare_func);
```

Here is the compare function:

```
int compare_func(const void *a, const void *b){
const struct HashItem* aa = (HashItem*)a;
    const struct HashItem* bb = (HashItem*)b;
    int val_1 = aa->occurencies;
    int val_2 = bb->occurencies;

    if(val_1 == val_2){
    return 0;
    }else if(val_1 > val_2){
    return 1;
    }else{
    return -1;
    }
    }
```

Sorry for the formatting, i am new to asking questions here.

I hope you can help thankyou.

Array code :

```
/*DynArray is a dynamically resizing array that is used to hold values and retain size data throughout*/
typedef struct{
    int number_of_values; 
    int capacity;
    HashItem **items;
}DynArray;

/*Method to create a new dynamic array and return it */
DynArray* array_new(int file_size){
    DynArray *array = malloc(sizeof(DynArray));
    array->number_of_values = 0;
    array->capacity = file_size / 10;
    printf("capacity is %d " , array->capacity);
    array->items = malloc(sizeof(HashItem*)* array->capacity);
}

/*Method used to increase the size of the array and reallocate memory*/
void array_increase_if_full(DynArray *array){
    if (array->number_of_values >= array->capacity){
        array->capacity *= 1.25;
        array->items = realloc(array->items, sizeof(HashItem)*array->capacity);
    }
}

/*Method to add a string to the dynamic array specified */
void array_append(DynArray *array, HashItem *item){
    array_increase_if_full(array);
    array->items[array->number_of_values] = item;
    //printf("item %s added \n at position %d ", array->items[array->number_of_values]->word, array->number_of_values);
    array->number_of_values++;
}

/*Method used to get value at specified position for given array*/
HashItem *array_get(DynArray *array, int position){
    if(position >= array->number_of_values || position <0){
        printf("Index specified out of range");
        exit(1);
    }
    //printf("item %s at position %d retrieved", array->items[position]->word, position);
    return array->items[position];
}

HashItem **array_getarray(DynArray *array){
    HashItem **toreturn[array->number_of_values];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < array->number_of_values; i++){
        toreturn[i] = array_get(array, i);
    }
    return toreturn;
}
```

Printing the array from the main gives the correct unsorted values of word:occurences

Edit:

Thanks to everyone that took their time to help, it is now in a working state with Michaels suggestion, i no longer use the array_getarray() method and instead use:

```
int n = array->number_of_values;
int i;
HashItem **standard_array = malloc(n*sizeof(HashItem*));
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    standard_array[i] = array_get(array, i);
    printf("%s : %d \n" , standard_array[i]->word, standard_array[i]->occurences);
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a problem with arrays and pointers. Do you want an array of HashItem structs or an array of pointers to HashItem structs? Currently you have a bit of both, which cannot work.

Comment: Hello, i want an array of HashItem pointers i believe. I have an array of HashItems which hold values and i want to sort these, but i used a self implemented vector like array to allow it to be dynamic so i first try to convert it to a standard array.

Comment: You have introduced absolutely meaningless allocations and copies in `compare_func`. Don't do that.

Comment: If you have an array of structs then you don't want an array of pointers. You want only one array, not two. If you are not sure what you have, show all relevant variable, type and function definitions (array, array_getarray) so that we can see.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and continued help, added relevant information you asked for.

Comment: I'm sorry to break it for you but mos everything in the code you have shown is totally wrong. Let's look at `array_getarray`. What the *heck* is it supposed to do? It doesn't do anything meaningful or even formally valid, so I'm totally at loss. Can you explain?

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, id rather hear it how it is. Honestly this is my first time going this deep into c and when it starts pointing to pointers it can get very confusing fast for me, i just took HashItem** to be an array of hashitems mistakenly. It was meant to turn the DynArray structure into an array that could be passed into qsort(). 

That method is no longer being used. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You structure declaration:

```
    typedef struct {
    char *word;
    int occurences;
    } HashItem;
```

declares a typedef name for an anonymous struct.  There is a `HashItem` type that's a structure, but there is no `struct HashItem` type.

So when your `compare_func()` has the following declarations:

```
const struct HashItem* aa = (HashItem*)a;
const struct HashItem* bb = (HashItem*)b;
```

those `struct HashItem*` variables are pointers to a forward declared `struct HashItem` that has nothign to do with the HashItem strucuture above.

Just change those variable declarations to:

```
const HashItem* aa = (HashItem*)a;
const HashItem* bb = (HashItem*)b;
```

and/or change the declaration of the structure to:

```
    typedef struct HashItem {
    char *word;
    int occurences;
    } HashItem;
```

However, there's another issue (as mentioned in other answers): you are apparently sorting an array of pointers to `HashItem` objects, but your `compare_function()` is being written as if you're sorting an array of the objects (not pointers).

To address this:

```
int compare_func(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    // get HashItem*'s from the HashItem**'s
    const HashItem* aa = *((HashItem**)a);
    const HashItem* bb = *((HashItem**)b);

    int val_1 = aa->occurencies;
    int val_2 = bb->occurencies;

    if (val_1 == val_2) {
        return 0;
    } else if (val_1 > val_2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Finally (for now anyway), this function is returning the address to a local array, so the data it points to is no longer valid:

```
HashItem **array_getarray(DynArray *array){
    HashItem **toreturn[array->number_of_values];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < array->number_of_values; i++){
        toreturn[i] = array_get(array, i);
    }
    return toreturn;
}
```

I think you'll need to allocate the array you're retuning using `malloc()` or `calloc()` or something.  But what I really think you need to do is step back and create some drawing of your data structures and think about the lifetime of the various objects contained in them and how those lifetimes can be tracked an managed so that you don't have leaks, double frees, or pointer dereferences to no longer valid objects.

Comment: Thanks for a very indepth answer, i have changed the struct, and replaced the compare function with yours but it still crashes, just before setting val_1 and val_2  (no error messages, just crashes, reaches up until then)

Sorry did not see your edit, so its a problem with the overall layout of my data structure? That makes complete sense what you are saying now, so is there a way to turn my array implementation into a standard array?

Comment: @Excessum: is C++ an option?  `std::vector<>` would make a lot of this much simpler.

Comment: To add to this i have now fixed the problem temporarily, and will work on improving my data structure and memory management in general, to fix it i just allocated memory to the array in main() and then where i was printing before, i also put the value into the newly made array, so i no longer use the get_array() method. 

Thanks alot

Im afraid not, this is academic work specifically in the C99 compiler, im rather inexperienced in c as you can see, so the help has been great

Answer (score 0):

It now looks to me like your problems are all springing from the first definition.

```
/*DynArray is a dynamically resizing array that is used to hold values and retain size data throughout*/
typedef struct{
    int number_of_values; 
    int capacity;
    HashItem **items;
}DynArray;
```

I see no reason for `items` to be a double-pointer. The comment says it should contain values, but a double-pointer pointing to an array would contain *pointers*, not the ultimate values. I think this initial misstep is causing you to trip everywhere else. Change it to

```
    ...
    HashItem *items;
    ...
```

and the rest *should* flow more naturally.

Comment: Thanks for the response, its all in one file and it is declared above.   

Hope you can continue to help, thanks alot!

Comment: I have completely changed my answer, it should supplement the excellent advice given by Michael Burr.

Comment: Thanks alot, i plan to improve my code taking into account what everyone has said, now its in a working state i'll use this as a backup and move to improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Change `qsort(standard_array, n, sizeof(HashItem), compare_func);` to

```
qsort(standard_array, n, sizeof(HashItem*), compare_func);
```

In function `void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));`

the third parameter `size_t size` stands for:

> Size in bytes of each element in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've made the appriopriate change and it was a silly mistake but it still wont compile. I changed the compare function but now it crashes after going calling qsort(), it calls a print function just before but not after. Hope you can help. Thanks

I've updated the source code appropriately. 

Hope you can continue to help, thanks alot!

Comment: Could you paste code of function `array_getarray()`.

Comment: How do implement this function `array_get()`? I you feel ok, please send your whole code to my mail. I will help check your code.

Comment: Hi, I have modified the code, but i can't run it, because of i don't have the input file. You can find the code here:http://ideone.com/SH2mSh

Comment: Thanks, i'll modify my code accordingly, looks like some nice changes in there to make the code more readable.